# ParseUser.saveInBackground never updates database

Tags: android, kotlin, parse-platform

I have a user such that

```
@ParseClassName("_User")
class User : ParseUser() {
    var firstName by ParseDelegate<String?>()
    var lastName by ParseDelegate<String?>()
}

open class ParseDelegate<T> {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    operator fun getValue(parseObj: ParseObject, propertyMetadata: KProperty<*>): T {
        return parseObj.get(propertyMetadata.name) as T
    }

    operator fun setValue(parseObj: ParseObject, propertyMetadata: KProperty<*>, a: Any?) {
        if (a != null) {
            parseObj.put(propertyMetadata.name, a)
            parseObj.saveEventually()
        }
    }
}
```

with a setup such that

```
val parseBuilder = Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId(BuildConfig.PARSE_APP_ID)
            .server(BuildConfig.PARSE_SERVER)

ParseUser.registerSubclass(User::class.java)

Parse.initialize(parseBuilder.build())
```

I try to edit it such that

```
val user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser() as User
user.firstName = newFirstName
user.lastName = newLastName

user.saveInBackground {
            if (it == null) {
                Timber.d("[user] user changes saved")
            }

            it?.apply { Timber.d("[user] issue saving user changes ${it.message}") }
        }
```

The save triggers the changes saved block, and if i navigate away from that fragment and back, the changes are saved to ParseUser.getCurrentUser, however, when i go to my parse database in the cloud, no changes have been saved and first/last name are still null.

any hints as to what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this line is messing up things: `parseObj.saveEventually()`. Can you try without it?

Comment: So turns out somehow I was missing a required field on the user object. The error that should have been raised, wasn’t. Using a Put before the save in background helped make this issue apparent. The error was being swallowed by the saveEventually

Answer (score 0):

The save eventually above was hiding a missing required field on the user object. Changing it / logging / using a put prior to the save in background made this clearer